# Weird Content Type Redirect HttpWebRequest C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-headers, httpwebrequest, fiddler

Code:

```
webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://---.com/bbb.aspx") as HttpWebRequest;
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
            webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            webRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1:8888");
            webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36";
            webRequest.Referer = "https://---.com/bbb.aspx";
            webRequest.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 1;
            webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            webRequest.ServicePoint.SetTcpKeepAlive(true, 15, 200);
            webRequest.ServicePoint.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
            webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
```

its redirected to ccc.aspx..the http header (Fiddler) is

```
POST https://---.com/bbb.aspx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)       Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36
Referer: https://---.com/bbb.aspx
Host: ---.com
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=************; skysales=**********
Content-Length: 1753
```

and it's successful direct to ccc.aspx, but why the content type header is **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** too, in fiddler, it's GET request, not POST

```
GET https://---.com/ccc.aspx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)    Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36
Host: ---.com
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=*********; skysales=********
```

Comment: HTTP redirects always use GET.

Comment: yes, but why content type in fiddler show Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded when GET?? @SLaks

Comment: That sounds like a bug in HttpWebRequest.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in `HttpWebRequest`, on [this line of code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/HttpWebRequest.cs#5686).

When handling redirect responses, they correctly reset the method, but do not remove related headers.

Comment: wow, this be big trouble to me..you have any suggestions or way to reset method when redirect ? thank you @Slaks

Comment: Let's be clear: HTTP requests do NOT `always use GET`. Browsers adopted the non-standard behavior of converting `POST` to `GET` for `HTTP/301` & `HTTP/302`. `HTTP/303` and `HTTP/307` were introduced to deal with the ambiguity in the original specification. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/19/understanding-the-impact-of-redirect-response-status-codes-on-http-methods-like-head-get-post-and-delete.aspx. Even with that change, there's nothing which says what headers ought to be changed on the new request if the method is changed.